# How to point a CNAME to an OpenShift route

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

My application that is hosted on OpenShift has a route with a URL that looks like this:

https://books-student-book-reservation-backend-project.apps.amarige.hostname.us

I want to give end users a URL that looks like this: https://breeze.us. First it hides the OpenShift URL structure, second it is easier to remember. Bottom line it's more user friendly.

The challenge is that when I redirect breeze.us to the OpenShift route, I get "Application is not available" error from OpenShift.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.openshift.com/online/pro/dev_guide/routes.html#custom-route-and-hosts-and-certificates-restrictions

## If you are using OpenShift Online

In OpenShift Online Starter, custom hostname is not permitted.  You can either buy OpenShift Online Pro (which allows custom hostname to be set), or use a reverse proxy to redirect your traffic (from another server with the custom hostname) to OpenShift.

## If you are using self-deployed OKD

You can set a custom hostname for your route like this:

```yaml
# A example unsecured route with custom hostname
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: route-unsecured
spec:
  host: www.your-custom-hostname.com  # here
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: service-name
```

If you need to serve multiple routes under the same hostname, you can also do path-based route with custom hostname:

```yaml
# A example unsecured path-based route with custom hostname
apiVersion: v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  name: route-unsecured
spec:
  host: www.your-custom-hostname.com
  path: "/test"      # here
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: service-name
```

So that you can use `www.your-custom-hostname.com/test` to access your route.

Comment: I actually have my own OKD 4.8 deployment. I am not using OpenShift Online.

Comment: @BillyBilly That's a critical bit of information. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome. That did the job.